# Passing nil to a function with an optional generically constrained parameter in a protocol extension

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift3

I have a situation where I declare two functions in a protocol, one of them takes an optional generically constrained parameter, the other function takes no parameters, but needs to be implemented in an extension as a default function where it calls the one with a parameter and passes `nil`. However I get this error:

> Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

My code:

```
public protocol MenuAccessible {
    var menuEntryViewController: UIViewController { get }
}

public protocol MenuTabBarControllerProtocol {
    func reloadTabs<T>(from uiProvider: T?) where T: MenuAccessible
    func reloadTabs()
}

public extension MenuTabBarControllerProtocol {
    func reloadTabs() {
        reloadTabs(from: nil) // error here, can't infer type
    }
}
```

Obviously the compiler is not able to infer the type. If I for example pass a `nil` (`Optional`) of the required type, then the compiler is happy. For example:

```
struct MenuAccessibleObject: MenuAccessible {
    var menuEntryViewController: UIViewController { return UIViewController() }
}

public extension MenuTabBarControllerProtocol {
    func reloadTabs() {
        let menuAccessible: MenuAccessibleObject? = nil
        reloadTabs(from: menuAccessible) // passes nil, but compiler is happpy
    }
}
```

Is there a way to pass nil in my default function implementation and not have to create that dummy object?

Comment: I tried that already, didn't work.

Comment: not knowing the internal implementation of `reloadTabs`, would it be fine to pass `self` instead of nil?

Comment: Like, `public extension MenuTabBarControllerProtocol where Self: MenuAccessible {
    func reloadTabs() {
        reloadTabs(from: self)
    }
}`

Comment: @Kamran if I try your suggestion then the implementing object requires to implement the `reloadTabs()` function, which defeats the idea of a default function.

Comment: @Kamran and self will never be nil. My `reloadTabs<T>(from uiProvider: T?) where T: MenuAccessible` checks if `uiProvider` object is nil and does things accordingly. That's why I want the default funciton to pass nil.

Comment: Yes, if you are using nil internally then passing `self` is not a good idea.

Comment: @AuRis The code `reloadTabs(from: Optional<MenuAccessibleObject>.none)` will  works but `reloadTabs(from: Optional<MenuAccessible>.none)` does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you are Using Generic `T` there if you are defining type is `MenuAccessible`

Following is simply compiler without any issue

```
public protocol MenuAccessible {
    var menuEntryViewController: UIViewController { get }
}

public protocol MenuTabBarControllerProtocol {
    func reloadTabs(from uiProvider: MenuAccessible?)
    func reloadTabs()

}

public extension MenuTabBarControllerProtocol {
    func reloadTabs() {
        reloadTabs(from: nil)
    }

}

public extension MenuTabBarControllerProtocol {
    func reloadTabs(from uiProvider: MenuAccessible?)  {
        fatalError() // implement me
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I don't know this will work for you or not but try this

```
public protocol MenuAccessible {
    var menuEntryViewController: UIViewController { get }
}


public class UIProvider:NSObject {

}

public protocol MenuTabBarControllerProtocol {

    func reloadAllTheItems<T>(from uiProvider: T?) where T: UIProvider, T: MenuAccessible
    func reloadTabs()
}

public extension MenuTabBarControllerProtocol {

    func reloadTabs() {
        self.reloadAllTheItems(from: Temp())
    }

    func reloadAllTheItems (provider:(UIProvider &  MenuAccessible)) {

    }


}

class Temp: (UIProvider &  MenuAccessible) {
    var menuEntryViewController: UIViewController {
        return UIViewController()
    }

}
```

Comment: I have simplified my problem in the question. The parameter has multiple constraints. `T` also has to be a subclass of `UIProvider` which is a subclass of `NSObject`.

Comment: My actual problem: `func reloadTabs<T>(from uiProvider: T?) where T: UIProvider, T: MenuAccessible`. `UIProvider` is a subclass of `NSObject`

Comment: What is your UIProvider is used for ?

Comment: To determine which tab should be selected after the they've been reloaded. If `nil` is passed then do not select a particular tab. A `UIProvider` which conforms to `MenuAccessible` represents a tab in my app. Your answer would work if I was on Swift 4. I could do `func reloadTabs(from uiProvider: (MenuAccessible & UIProvider)?)`

Comment: @AuRis As your are mixing up Class and Protocol so it is quite difficult to provide default implementation still you can check this

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that dummy object was what I wanted to avoid in the first place. Since `MenuAccessible` has many required properties and functions, I do not wan to implement it. I will just have to rethink my strategy.